# Azure Logic App (Standard Plan) Variable condition assessment not consistent

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app (Standard Plan) which takes messages from a service bus queue and stores the contents in a data lake. The messages originate from devices in the field that upload telemetry via an IoT hub.

The messages contain the name of the device. Some have a prefix in the device name of X and some Y. (for example)

Depending on if the device name starts X or Y, I am changing the path in the data lake where the data is saved.

I set a variable at the start of the flow and then change the variable using a control -> condition evaluation. This is within a FOR EACH LOOP. Depending on if the device name starts with X or Y, it will then change the variable to the path I want for saving the blob.

I then reset the variable at the end of the FOR EACH back to 0.

I am finding that the evaluation works correctly 90% of the time. However, sometimes it will place data for X in Y's folder in the data lake... despite having correctly evaluated the device previously from an earlier run.

Nothing indicates anything is out of the ordinary when reviewing the run detail.

Why is my variable and control condition not consistently evaluating the data?

[image: Flow]

[image: Init Var]

[image: Eval]

[image: True]

[image: False]

[image: Create Blob]

Answer (score 0):

For each runs parallel by default.

Set Setting -> Concurrency -> Degree of Parallelism to 0.

Comment: In a consumption plan, I know how to do that; how about a standard plan logic app?